# Como carregar uma tabela Excel e transforma-la em uma tabela HTML utilizando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-excel

Pretendo criar um botão para carregar um arquivo xls ou csv e transformar essa tabela do Excel em uma tabela HTML, como posso fazer isso utilizando JavaScript? Por favor...

Comment: Você vai precisar de uma linguagem de programação. Sugiro adicionar a linguagem de sua preferência nas tags, para que a gente possa responder com exemplos nessa linguagem.

Comment: Ah sim, farei isso, obrigado!

Comment: @JuanLima você tentou a solução que eu lhe propus?

Answer (score 0):

Existe um plugin jQuery que possibilita a conversão de de arquivos .csv para JSON. Desta forma você consegue extrair os dados do arquivo e trabalhar com eles em tela como bem desejar.

Segue link do site oficial do plugin: [papaparse.com](http://papaparse.com/)

Fiz este código abaixo para testar o plugin (Você pode facilmente copiar e testar em seu computador):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste PapaParse</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://papaparse.com/resources/js/papaparse.js"></script>
    <style>
        td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin:auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnConverter').click(function(){

                // veja mais em: http://papaparse.com/docs#jquery
                $('input[type=file]').parse({
                    //definindo configuração
                    config : buildConfig()
                });
            });

            function buildConfig()
            {
                // função chamada quando completar a conversão
                return {complete: Complete};
            }

            function Complete(results)
            {
                // limpando conteudo da div
                $('#tabela_aqui').html('');
                // inserindo tabela na div
                $('<table id="tabela"></table>').appendTo('#tabela_aqui');
                // inserindo linhas
                for (var i = 0; i < results.data.length; i++) {
                    $('<tr></tr>').appendTo('#tabela');
                }
                // inserindo celulas nas linhas
                $('tr').each(function(key, val) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < results.data[0].length; j++) {
                        $(this).append('<td>'+results.data[key][j]+'</td>');
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Arquivo (.csv) <input type="file" name="csv_file"><br>
    <button id="btnConverter">Converter</button>
    <br/>
    <div id="tabela_aqui"></div>
</body></html>
```

O código acima disponibiliza um botão para selecionar o arquivo e outro que converte o arquivo em JSON e exibe em tela como uma tabela.

Nesse [link](http://papaparse.com/resources/files/normal.csv) há um arquivo .csv para testar a funcionalidade.